# Which routing file does my express/angular app use? Which takes precedence?

Tags: angularjs, express

I built a simple single page express app with Angular and I'm wondering which routes file does my application use and why?

My repo is [here](https://github.com/Jwan622/single_page_mean_stack)

In my repo, I have a node routes.js file in app/routes.js.

Inside that file, I have this line of code:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
            res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
        });
```

So I assume that above line of code takes any route and the response sends the public/index.html file which is this html file which loads a bunch of Angular scripts:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title>Starter Node and Angular</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- custom styles -->

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/NerdCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/NerdService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="NerdController">
  <div class="container">

      <!-- HEADER -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Stencil: Node and Angular</a>
          </div>

          <!-- LINK TO OUR PAGES. ANGULAR HANDLES THE ROUTING HERE -->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/nerds">Nerds</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

      <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
      <div ng-view></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

One of those scripts is this appRoutes.js file:

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })

        // nerds page that will use the NerdController
        .when('/nerds', {
            templateUrl: 'views/nerd.html',
            controller: 'NerdController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

My question:

1. On the first load of this app, and say we visit localhost:8080, are we hitting Express's route.js file and its * route? Or are we hitting Angular's appRoutes.js file and its / route? Which one takes precedence?
2. When we visit the /nerds route, why don't we hit Express' * route in the route.js file? Why do we default use the route defined inside the appRoutes.js file?

Comment: On the app first load the express route (Server Side) is hit and will return the static files of angular (html and js files) to the browser client.
After that the angular appRoutes.js will be processed (in the Client Side) and redirect the user for the right route. Angular put a '#' in the url, its change the browser url without hit the Server Side, pay attention in your browser url when you browse.

Comment: What is that # sign? Where is that # sign in my app? Does Angular do this automatically?

Comment: Care to write a more fleshed out answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: look this link, it's explains how angular routes works http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/routes.html

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your routing rules specified by your $routeProvider (inside your appRoutes.js file) are different than the rules you write for http requests in your routes.js configuration file.  As long as you have this set up in your server, you should be able to access your static files in your public folder, which I see you already have in your server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
//The line below specifies that you are using your public folder for static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./public")));
//The line below specifies your views folder
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './public/views'));

require('./server/config/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(8080);
```

If you do this, you don't need to specify the '*' in your app/routes.js, because this code will already know to pick up the index.html file within your public folder as the 'main' folder for your static files, and your localhost:8080 will automatically use index.html as it's 'base'.  You can remove the '*' app.get route in your routes.js.  If you want to send requests to and from your routes.js file, you have to do that through your factory using $http.get or $http.post.

Then, in your index.js file, you should have:

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

which allows you to access any of your routes within $routeProvider.  That way, localhost8080/ should pick up your .when '\' route in appRoutes.js.  You may or may not need the app.set('views', path.join... etc. line in the code above to allow access to the views/home.html and views/nerd.html files in your views folder, but it wouldn't hurt if you don't have it already.  Just make sure your requiring of express and path come before the rest of your code in your server file (which I see you already have done for 'express') if you want to use 'path'.  Requiring 'path' just allows more fluidity when other people with different operating systems are trying to use your code.

Let me know if this helps.